# getElementById not getting the id in wordpress 3.3.1

Tags: javascript, wordpress, getelementbyid

i am building a wordpress site, twenty eleven theme. I want a widget area to be shown only on a certain page.

so added a javascript function to the `<head>` which is called by     `<body onload="show_collection_area">`

The function called, since the    console.log(obj.id) writes "text-2" to the console (which is the right id). But when i set visibilty to none in this function:

```
function show_collection_area(){
    if (document.location == "http://dutchmountaineer.com/wp/?page_id=116"){
        obj = document.getElementById('text-2');
        obj.style.visibility = 'visible';
        console.log(obj.id)
        console.log(obj);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("text-2").style.visibility = 'none';
    }
}
```

nothin happens. I tried calling the function from the page itself by using a button but the result is the same.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

PS the whole code:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Eleven
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 6]>
<html id="ie6" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html id="ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html id="ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 6) | !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
</head>

<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title><?php
    /*
     * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
     */
    global $page, $paged;

    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

    // Add the blog name.
    bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description";

    // Add a page number if necessary:
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyeleven' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

    ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php
    /* We add some JavaScript to pages with the comment form
     * to support sites with threaded comments (when in use).
     */
    if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );


    /* Always have wp_head() just before the closing </head>
     * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
     * generally use this hook to add elements to <head> such
     * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
     */
    wp_head();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("button").hide();
  });
});

function show_collection_area(){
    if (document.location == "http://dutchmountaineer.com/wp/?page_id=116"){
        obj = document.getElementById('text-2');
        obj.style.visibility = 'visible';
        console.log(obj.id)
        console.log(obj);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("text-2").style.visibility = 'none';
    }
}

function display_gallery(id)
{   
    //first we set all displays to none
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload = "show_collection_area()" <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed">
    <header id="branding" role="banner">
            <hgroup>
                <h1 id="site-title"><span><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></span></h1>
                <h2 id="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
            </hgroup>

            <?php
                // Check to see if the header image has been removed
                $header_image = get_header_image();
                if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) :
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                <?php
                    // The header image
                    // Check if this is a post or page, if it has a thumbnail, and if it's a big one
                    if ( is_singular() &&
                            has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) &&
                            ( /* $src, $width, $height */ $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), array( HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH, HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH ) ) ) &&
                            $image[1] >= HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH ) :
                        // Houston, we have a new header image!
                        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'post-thumbnail' );
                    else : ?>
                    <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH; ?>" height="<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT; ?>" alt="" />
                <?php endif; // end check for featured image or standard header ?>
            </a>
            <?php endif; // end check for removed header image ?>

            <?php
                // Has the text been hidden?
                if ( 'blank' == get_header_textcolor() ) :
            ?>
                <div class="only-search<?php if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) : ?> with-image<?php endif; ?>">
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php
                else :
            ?>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <nav id="access" role="navigation">
                <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Main menu', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
                <?php /*  Allow screen readers / text browsers to skip the navigation menu and get right to the good stuff. */ ?>
                <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
                <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#secondary" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
                <?php /* Our navigation menu.  If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back to wp_page_menu. The menu assiged to the primary position is the one used. If none is assigned, the menu with the lowest ID is used. */ ?>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
            </nav><!-- #access -->
    </header><!-- #branding -->


    <div id="main">
```

Comment: The first thing you are doing wrong is showing a big pile of PHP when your question is about how JS, CSS and HTML are interacting with each other.

Comment: Sorry, that is the second thing you are doing wrong. The first thing you are doing wrong is using client side JS to determine what is shown on pages instead of doing it in your PHP.

Comment: The second code block is to provide context if necessary. Wouldn't know beforehand whether someone would be asking for it. 
If your comments aren't constructive, please refrain from posting them in the future. thank you

Comment: — They are constructive. Seriously. You are better off solving the problem in PHP and not JS, and when you do have a question about client side stuff, you are better off showing the HTML output from PHP and not the PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value for "visibility" should be "hidden" when you want it to be hidden. The "none" value works for "display".